# Materialize Css Parallex is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, materialize

I am trying to use the parallax within a react component. I have gotten this to work in the past. This is a MeteorJs project as well

I get a console error:

> $(...).parallax is not a function

My component:

```
  import React from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';


export default class Index extends React.Component{
    render(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.parallax').parallax();
        });
        return(
          <div className="container">

              <div className="parallax-container">
                  <div className="parallax"><img src="images/parallax1.jpg"/></div>
              </div>
              <div className="section white">
                  <div className="row container">
                      <h2 className="header">Parallax</h2>
                      <p className="grey-text text-darken-3 lighten-3">Parallax is an effect where the background
                          content or image in this case, is moved at a different speed than the foreground content while
                          scrolling.</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="parallax-container">
                  <div className="parallax"><img src="images/parallax2.jpg"/></div>
              </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My client main.js file:

```
import '../imports/startup/client/routes';
import '../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min';
import '../node_modules/materialize-css/js/parallax';
```

Comment: Stuck at the same part. Found any solution??

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that .parallax() isn't a function in this line of code:

``
$('.parallax').parallax();
```

Which means that `$('.parallax')` is returning an object (usually a html element). It is not surprising that `.parallax()` is not a function, because it's just a html element.

Looking at the documentation, I think you are missing this initialisation code:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
     var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.parallax');
     var instances = M.Parallax.init(elems, options);   });
```

Comment: I think in this case, it'll say `M` is not defined :')